# serializeArray have unwanted extra array wrap

Tags: php, jquery, serialization

I'm using serializeArray() for getting the form input element values, but when i do there are was one extra array wrap, how to avoid this

```
<form method="post" class="form" action="<?=site_url('update_description');?>" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$info['id'];?>">
  <textarea placeholder="Enter Property Description" class="form-control" name="description" rows="4" required><?= $info['description'];?></textarea>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm">Update Description</button>   
<script>        
</form>
$('.form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var params = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), 
    {params},
    function(data){
        //console.log(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

and i'm getting data like this in controller

```
Array
(
[params] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => id
                [value] => 44
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => description
                [value] => hello
            )

    )

 )
```

Comment: Can you show how to the result must look?

Comment: see, i'm using ci validation, it should come same as how it'll come when we use normal post ,php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) in order to convert your output to a post parameter  shaped as an object of pairs name/value:

```
var params = $(this).serializeArray().reduce(function(acc, ele) {
      acc[ele.name] = ele.value;
      return acc;
}, {});
```

Moreover, you need to change from:

```
{params},
```

to:

```
params,
```

```js
$('.form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var params = $(this).serializeArray().reduce(function(acc, ele) {
      acc[ele.name] = ele.value;
      return acc;
  }, {});
  console.log(params);
  
  
  return;
  // useless for test
  $.post($(this).attr('action'),
          params,
          function(data){
              //console.log(data);
          });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form method="post" class="form" action="<?=site_url('update_description');?>" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$info['id'];?>">
    <textarea placeholder="Enter Property Description" class="form-control" name="description" rows="4" required><?= $info['description'];?></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm">Update Description</button>
</form>
```

Comment: So you are saying an seializearray() will not same as an normal post array ?

Comment: @RanjithM Yes, when you need to pass arguments to a post in the form of object pairs name/value you need to convert (reduce) the array to the right type. See the output of my snippet.

Comment: @RanjithM Doubts, problems? Let me know If I can help you

Comment: Thanks bro changed {params} to params, that worked !! no need of reduce function @gaetanoM

Answer (score 0):

Juste use serialize() instead.

```
$('form').serialize();
```

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/